# Maintenance plan is backing up database transaction log but it is not selected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction-log, maintenance-plans

I have a strange problem, the transaction log for my database is being backed up however it is not selected.

*I change the names of the server and databases in the screenshots to protect my information from the bad guys.* ;)

Here is the issue that server "XYZ" is having, the screen shot below is showing the sub-plan for the "Transaction Log Backup" maintenance job. As you can see here "Database2" is showing up in the plan task.

[image: Plan task]

However in the properties plan task "Database2" is not selected. In order for the transaction log to be backed up the database has to be selected, like "Database1", right?

[image]

Despite the fact that "Database2" is not selected the transaction log is being backed up. I verified the properties of the database when the last transaction log was done.

So, I am a little confused about this and would like to know if anyone else here came across this and how you resolved it.

Server specs: SQL Server 2008 SP2 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your radio button is on **All user databases** and **NOT** on **These Databases**

Comment: Yep. The checkboxes are ignored if the radio button is set elsewhere.

Comment: I sent the wrong screen shot, the original screen shot has "These databases" selected. I was experimenting to see if I changed the setting if that would resolve this issue. The transaction log for this database is still backed up even thou the database is not selected.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that THIS maintenance plan is the one creating the transaction log backups for Database2?  How are you determining that the transaction log for Database2 is being backed up?  Are you running a script against MSDB?  If so, can you post the script your running?  Also, when you're in the maintenance plan wizard and double click on the Backup Database task, try clicking View T-SQL - what do you see?

Comment: Can you create another maintenance plan choosing only database1, test it out and delete the current one if the new maint plan does what you want?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I can see the all the transaction log (TRN) backups in the SQLBACKUPS folder and I have confirmed the TSQL script is in the maintenance plan. 

 BACKUP LOG [Database2] TO  DISK = N'I:\SQLBACKUPS\TransactionLogBackup\Database2\Database2_backup_2017_02_16_144301_2044575.trn' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Database2_backup_2017_02_16_144301_2044575', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

Comment: Interesting, I created a new "Test" maintenance job and I was able to save "database1" and "database2" together. I then went back into the test maintenance job and I can see that both database were still selected. So, why do you think the other maintenance job can't do the same?

Comment: It's hard to tell and I haven't been able to reproduce your problem - could be a bug in the 2008 maintenance plan wizard.  I think you might be better off creating a brand new maintenance plan that does what you want and delete the existing one.

Comment: This is why I use backup scripts that aren't part of maintenance plans. Like those from https://ola.hallengren.com/ -- that way I know what's going on under the GUI.